# Are connected regular curves parametrized regular curves?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces

In Do Carmo' Differential Geometry book, the author defines regular curves as follows:

> A regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subset $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ with the following property: For each point $p \in C$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and an infinite differentiable homeomorphism $\alpha: I \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow V \cap C$ ($I$ is an open interval) such that $\alpha'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t \in I$.

He also defines parametrized regular curves as follows

> A parametrized regular curve is a function $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $I$ is an open interval, $\gamma$ is infinitely differentiable and $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$.

Here is my question:

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $ a regular *connected* curve. Does there exist a parametrized regular curve $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\gamma(I)=C$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example a circle minus one point $X=C(O,1)\setminus(0,-1)$ has parametrization $t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ which is a homeomorphism from $]-\pi,\pi[$ to $X$.

Comment: This is an example though. However, it indicates that homeomorphism is too much to ask, if we want to parametrize the whole curve. So, I edited my question to exclude this requirement.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but here we have $\gamma:(-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^3$ verify the definition and $\gamma((-pi,pi))=X$.

Comment: But, what if $C$ is the whole circle? Then the parametrization is no longer homeomorphism.

Comment: Your question was: does there exist a parametrized curves such that ...
The reponse is yes. If your question is: does there always exist a global parametrization, the answer is no.

Comment: And for the whole circle such a global parametrization doesn't exist.

Comment: In my updated question, I don't require $\gamma$ to be homeomorphic.

Comment: Ok, so for the whole circle the same parametrization works if we don't require homeomorphy (but with intervale $(-2\pi,2\pi)$)

Comment: Correct, my question is whether this is a general theorem.

Comment: Ah ok: can we patching all these parametrization together? I don't know!